# Design Thinking: Simple, but interesting challenges

Tags: design, agile, design-thinking

I am planning to hold a Design Thinking Workshop in my Company (IT-Consulting). Given time Frame is 4-6 hours.

I want the participants to go through the whole process by themselves, so they have the highest learning effect. For doing that, I want to use a simple, but fantastic example, which shows them how cool DT can be.

Unfortunately, I am a bit uncreative. I dont want to reuse the example I learned DT with (students eating unhealthy Food). It should be something that is not too IT-related, but is relatable to most People.
Can you maybe give me a hint?

Comment: This question is off topic and will likely be closed. The answers will primarily be opinion based, and only of real value to you in your specific situation. For what it's worth - considering you're not quite sure what you're doing, 4-6 hours is a LONG time. Check out this excellent DT workshop. Covers everything in around an hour, shortened to 30mins in the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z4gAugRGpeY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These workshops are often best when competitive. Split them into groups of roughly 4-5 people (allowing for larger teams if your number of groups reaches a dozen) and have them build a startup by designing an app that "uberizes" an industry that everyone is familiar with. Some good examples here are grocery delivery, lawn care, corporate chef service, hardware as a service, or babysitting.

Give them a discovery phase where they can speculate broadly about customer needs and then have the teams discuss together what each team's ideas were. Score each team's input, pointing out any obvious flaws to course correct and a strength of each. Explain pivoting and how we need to adapt to change and learn from competitors, the market, and consumer trends. The teams revisit, change their plans, and come up with a more solid idea. Have them draw the home page of the app with markers, suggesting that having multiple variations is okay. Have the teams come together again to reveal their work and score them again. Point out areas where each design didn't meet a given KPI according to fake data. Give them another round to adapt and change before coming back to final scoring. If time allows, add more rounds in the middle to adapt to new changes and conditions. Add a new federal regulation that throws things into chaos. Add a new tech platform, the app needs to work on VR or Amazon Alexa now.

Hopefully, some of this can help. The question is a bit subjective, but it's an important question nonetheless.